# Could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to create an ephemeral key in my IOS app. I can successfully create a stripe customer that saves in my firebase console and on my stripe dashboard. However, when I try to create the ephemeral key, I am receiving the error in my ios console after trying to view the checkout controller.

> 'Could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider. Make sure your backend is sending the unmodified JSON of the ephemeral key to your app.

and on my firebase function logs I am seeing,

> createEphemeralKey
> Request has incorrect Content-Type.

> createEphemeralKey
> Invalid request, unable to process.

in my index.js file, the code that I am using is

```
exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  var stripeVersion = data.api_version;
  const customerId = data.customer_id;

  return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customerId},
    {stripe_version: stripeVersion}
  ).then((key) => {
    return key
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
})
```

Below is how I create my stripe customer.

```
    exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: user.email,
  }).then((customer) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${user.uid}/customer_id`).set(customer.id);
  });
});
```

and then myAPIClient looks like.

```
    enum APIError: Error {
     case unknown

     var localizedDescription: String {
         switch self {
         case .unknown:
             return "Unknown error"
         }
     }
 }

static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()
var baseURLString: String? = "https://myProject.cloudfunctions.net/"
var baseURL: URL {
    if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        return url
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}

   func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
        "api_version": apiVersion,
        ])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { responseJSON in
            switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

On my checkOutVC, I have

```
var stripePublishableKey = "pk_test_testProjectKey"
var backendBaseURL: String? = "https://myProject.cloudfunctions.net"

        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())

    init(price: Int, settings: Settings) {
        
        if let stripePublishableKey = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StripePublishableKey") {
            self.stripePublishableKey = stripePublishableKey
        }
        if let backendBaseURL = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StripeBackendBaseURL") {
            self.backendBaseURL = backendBaseURL
        }
        let stripePublishableKey = self.stripePublishableKey
        let backendBaseURL = self.backendBaseURL
        
        assert(stripePublishableKey.hasPrefix("pk_"), "You must set your Stripe publishable key at the top of acceptWorker.swift to run this app.")
        assert(backendBaseURL != nil, "You must set your backend base url at the top of acceptWorker.swift to run this app.")
        
        Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey(self.stripePublishableKey)
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        config.appleMerchantIdentifier = self.appleMerchantID
        config.companyName = self.companyName
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = settings.requiredBillingAddressFields
        config.requiredShippingAddressFields = settings.requiredShippingAddressFields
        config.shippingType = settings.shippingType
        config.additionalPaymentOptions = settings.additionalPaymentOptions
        config.cardScanningEnabled = true
        self.country = settings.country
        self.paymentCurrency = settings.currency
        
        self.theme = settings.theme
        MyAPIClient.sharedClient.baseURLString = self.backendBaseURL
  
        let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: settings.theme)
        self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.paymentContext.delegate = self
        self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self
        self.paymentContext.paymentAmount = 5000 // This is in cents, i.e. $50 USD

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

I apologize for the long lines of code but I am really running into a brick wall. Why isnt the backend creating the ephemeralKey for customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are jumping out at me:

- You’ve written a callable type function (using `onCall`) but you’re
  trying to call it with a normal HTTP request. These functions need to
  be called with Firebase’s client library
  (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).
  This stack overflow answer provides some great links about this:
  [Firebase Cloud Function to delete user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487797/firebase-cloud-function-to-delete-user).
- Your firebase function is parsing `stripe_version` and `customer_id` from
  `data`, but your request is only sending `api_version`. Where in your
  code are you sending `stripe_version` and `customer_id`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated to show how I am sending customer_id. It is when I call exports.createStripeCustomer. Should I be sending the stripe_version and the ephemeral key as well?

Comment: Ah, then you shouldn't be trying to parse out `customer_id` from `data`. Since you set it in the database, you'll have to retrieve it from the database when you need it.

Comment: but the stripe customers is fine?

Comment: Also, should I be creating the stripe_version when the customer is initially created?

Comment: You can just use the `api_version` as the stripe_version since you're sending it as part of the request when you create the ephemeral key

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have updated my code can you tell me if this is correct or not?

Comment: You still need to change your client code to use the Firebase client library when calling your Firebase function (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function). The way you're doing it now with `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is not meant to be used with Firebase callable functions unless you implement the callable protocol yourself. The stack overflow answer I linked to explains this w/ better links

Comment: Thank you. What you're saying makes sense I am still just having trouble with the process. I marked you correct for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: the last question, I have found a quick fix and I changed my func createCustomerKey. Is this what I should be headed towards?

Comment: Yeah you're headed in the right direction, I still think `const customerId = data.customer_id;` needs to retrieve the customer ID from where you set it in your database but you should just try it out and see what happens